# Unquoted strings in function calls

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

In my Google Apps Script addon for Sheets, I have a custom function that will lookup prices. For example, a call like:

```
=LOOKUP_PRICE("apple")
```

would return the price for an apple. However, I've noticed that many users are not quoting the item name, instead just typing the following (which Sheets permits):

```
=LOOKUP_PRICE(apple)
```

When I try to retrieve the string value of the parameter with `toString()` all I get is the string `"#NAME?"`.

Is there a way to handle this scenario and ideally retrieve the value of the parameter when not quoted?

Alternatively, is there a good way to detect this case and show the appropriate error message? All I've come up with so far is the following, but it feels dirty:

```
param.toString().toLowerCase() === "#name?"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since these functions are written in JavaScript, as soon as you try to pass a string that isn't inside double quotes it will throw an error.

From the [Custom Functions Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions):

> Google Sheets stores data in different formats depending on the nature of the data. When these values are used in custom functions, Apps Script treats them as the appropriate data type in JavaScript.

This means the functions use the normal [JavaScript Data Structures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures) i.e. string, number etc.

---

Your only real option here is to educate your users on how to use the function properly.

The easiest thing you could do to advise your users is give the function a JsDoc `@customfunction` tag, which allows you to customize the help text for the function itself. This helps your users with the syntax of your custom function.

Here's a brief example that you could modify to suit your requirement:

```
/**
 * Searches for the price of the item specified.
 *
 * @param {"Apple"} item_to_find The item to find, e.g. "Apple", "Pear".
 * @return Price of the item specified.
 * @customfunction
 */
function LOOKUP_PRICE(item_to_find) {
  if (item_to_find === "Apple") {
    return "$4.99"; 
  } else {
    return "Not Found!";
  }
}
```

When we start to call the custom function, we get this:
[image: Help Text Example]

---

#### References:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [JavaScript Data Structures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures)

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware adding the `{"Apple"}` ahead of the parameter name would use that in the example text, which will help reduce confusion.